# The element type 'Set<DetailsCard>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, widget

```
Column(
          children: [
            Widget1(),
            Widget2(),
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                              for(var i =0 ;i<categories.length;i++){
                                DetailsCard(catName: categories[i]);
                              }
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

In the above code i want to add multiple widgets based on the items in the categories list . But when I try using the for loop i keep getting "The element type 'Set' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'." error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `for` statement inside of `[...]` like below:

```
Column(
          children: [
            Widget1(),
            Widget2(),
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                              for(var i =0 ;i<categories.length;i++)
                                DetailsCard(catName: categories[i])
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

do not add `{}` and `;` in `[...]` statement, it is illegal

Answer (score 0):

What I usually like to do with iterables is using `.map()` on `Iterables` (`List`, `Sets`). For example you could use:

```
Column(
   children: categories.map((category) => Text(category)).toList(),
),
```

If you have other Widgets in the `Column` other than the Widgets made from the iterables you could use the spread operator `...`.

```
Column(
  children: [
     ...categories.map((category) => Text(category)),
     Text('This is a text'),
  ],
),
```